# Can we fetch the button properties (like button text,button hidden status etc.) on button click through ICommand in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Am using ICommand(MVVM) for a button click event, but i have small doubt here.

When i use ICommand for button click event,can we access the properties of button as we do in button click event from code behind.

In code behind, easily through the sender object we can get the properties as shown below,

```
private void BtnClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        var datacontext = button.DataContext;
    }
```

Similarly can we do this in ICommand?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `MultiBinding` to pass parameters through your `ICommand` `CommandParameter` this will require `IMultiValueConverter`, don't pass the `Button` object as you will break `MvvM`.

Comment: if you don't mind, please can u give an simple example of how to do it.

Comment: What you have here is an X/Y problem.  You're asking how to do X, but what you really should be doing is Y.  X, in this case, is passing view elements into the view model.  Y, in this case, is passing in *the data that you need* from the view into the view model, or performing some other task on items in the view.  Unfortunately, you have told us *what* you are trying to do, but not **why**.  If you had stated why you need to get the button in the view model, we could have told you the better solution to your problem--the Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I would prefer because it keeps your `ViewModel` clear of any `View` stuff:

Bind the required property of the `Button` to a property in your `DataContext`. In your command implementation, use the corresponding property of the `DataContext`. (Assuming the `DataContext` is your `ViewModel` and also contains the command implementation.)

In MVVM, these properties should most likely (exept for few exceptions) have been set to their values using a binding to a property in the ViewModel, i.e. your ViewModel should already have properties corresponding to the required button properties. So why not simply use them in the command implementation?

---

If you still want to have the button available in the command implementation, you can bind `CommandParameter` to the `Button`:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyButton}"/>
```

and in the command implementation cast the parameter to `Button` and access its properties:

```
private void MyCommandImplementation(object prm)
{
    var button = prm as Button;
    //...
}
```

Alternatively, you could bind the required property (instead of the whole `Button`) to `CommandParameter`.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted, it was really helpful. 

But  @XAMlMAX mentioned that passing button object would break mvvm rules. So if there is any other to achieve it.

Comment: Yes, see the first part of my answer :-) However, this does not make the button itself available to the ViewModel (only the required properties). If it did, it would no longer be MVVM. MVVM is exactly about making the ViewModel unaware of the View and keeping any logic out of the View.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample implementation of how to use `MultiBinding` and `IMultiValueConverter`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace SO_app.Converters
{
    class MultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            foreach (var item in values)
            {
                //process the properties passed in
            }
            return new object();
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="SO_app.TestWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO_app"
    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:SO_app.Converters"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VM;assembly=VM"
    Title="TestWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <converter:MultiValueConverter x:Key="mvc"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" Content="Some value here">
        <Button.CommandParameter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource mvc}">
                <Binding Path="Visibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                <Binding Path="Content" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Button.CommandParameter>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

And here is what you will see in your VS:
[image: MultiValueConverter in debug]

Comment: Good answer (+1), but I'd argue that In MVVM, these properties should most likely (except for few exceptions) have been set to their values using a binding to a property in the ViewModel, i.e. your ViewModel should already have properties corresponding to the required button properties. So why not simply use them in the command implementation?

Comment: @wkl That would be true for a button, but if you have over 100 records to display on the screen (DataTemplate) then you will have to have a list of those in your ViewModel, with a converter your view takes care of this. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @XAMIMAX I do not see where this would be different: I assume the `DataTemplate` contains a `Button` which when clicked triggers a `Command` which somehow acts on the templated item. To be able to do that, you would have to use the templated item (record) as command parameter. Now, again, there is no need to pass the button's properties because they should have been filled from either a property of the ViewModel or of the templated item. Both are available to your implementation (remember you had to pass the templated item as a parameter anyway). Am I missing something?

Comment: @wkl If your record has properties to hold these values for Binding to a DataTemplate then yes this would not be beneficial but if you use record from database which doesn't need those properties, then you have to create a class that would extend your Model (record) so then you could use it in your view, and that would be the case with every class (record) you have in your app, this way you don't have to manipulate those and just let your View handle these.

Comment: @XAMIMAX If the record does not have these values, I conclude that the record will have no influence on the button. Also, we assume the button properties to not be defined by the ViewModel via Binding. So where would a value for the button's property come from? I think it can only be a default value or s.th. purely UI related (like ActualHeight...). The former should not be a problem and using the latter in the command seems not MVVM-like to me. I would subsum that under 'few exceptions'.

Comment: Anyway, I think this is a good answer when you really _need_ a button's properties. I only wanted to say that often, you will not really need them.

Comment: @wkl I wrote my answer this way because OP posted "_can we access the properties of button as we do in button click event from code behind._"

Answer (score 1):

You can bind button itself as CommandParameter

```
<Button Command="{Binding EditCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Comment: This will break MvvM as the ViewModel will now be aware of an UI element.

Comment: How Multibinding or IMultiValueConverter help ? What will be the return type from IMultiValueConverter ?

Comment: If you implement `IMultiValueConverter` you will get `object[] values` passed in, as opposed to `object value` in `IValueConverter`. MultiBinding will allow to pass each Properties i.e. Hidden property of a button or the text of the Button, keeping ViewModel AWAY from UI elements.

Comment: I am not sure what logic he is going to write inside command with Button. But I think If he needs button object itself inside command IMultiValueConverter cannot help. If he just needs some property values then IMultiValueConverter is a good option because as you said it will not violate MVVM.